# Sum without couting duplicate values SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table `suivis` containing columns id_action AND id_individu, that table can contain multiple duplicate value (not the entire row, only the column).

example : 
    [image]

I have also a table `individus` containing a column `statut_collaborateur`, that table can have two values : 'no' and 'granted'.

i need help to count the number of id_individu having statut_collaborateur = no and statut_collaborateur = granted but only once.

For now, i managed to do this :

```
SELECT  j.date_debut, j.date_fin, j.titre, so.id_identite, so.nom_societe,
        SUM(CASE WHEN (i.statut_collaborateur = 'granted') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS interne, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN (i.statut_collaborateur = 'no') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS externe, 
        r.nom_responsable 
FROM individus AS i 
    LEFT JOIN suivis AS s ON s.id_individu = i.id_individu 
    LEFT JOIN jurys AS j ON j.id_jury = s.id_jury 
    LEFT JOIN societes AS so ON so.id_societe = j.id_societe 
    LEFT JOIN responsables AS r ON r.id_responsable = j.id_responsable 
WHERE s.id_action = 22 
AND j.statut IN (1,3) 
AND j.date_debut BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-10-23 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY s.id_jury`
```

The major problem is that i have to do it in the sum, i tried count also but same result, my count is 5, it should be 3 ( 3 distinct individu).

Comment: Your LEFT JOINs turn into regular INNER JOINs when you have these s and j conditions in the WHERE clause. Move them to the ON clauses to get true LEFT JOIN result!

Comment: Your question mentions two tables.  Your query has five.  If two are sufficient, then simplify your query to have only those two.  If all five are needed, then explain what they are.

Comment: the 3 others tables are here to get some informations non-related to the question like date or title. i just put my query like i wrote it in my script. but my question is only related to the two tables i mentionned, sorry if that disturbed you

Answer (score 0):

Number of column in selection should need to include on group by

```
SELECT  j.date_debut, j.date_fin, j.titre, so.id_identite, so.nom_societe,
        SUM(CASE WHEN (i.statut_collaborateur = 'granted') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS interne, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN (i.statut_collaborateur = 'no') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS externe, 
        r.nom_responsable 
FROM individus AS i 
    LEFT JOIN suivis AS s ON s.id_individu = i.id_individu 
    LEFT JOIN jurys AS j ON j.id_jury = s.id_jury 
    LEFT JOIN societes AS so ON so.id_societe = j.id_societe 
    LEFT JOIN responsables AS r ON r.id_responsable = j.id_responsable 
WHERE s.id_action = 22 
AND j.statut IN (1,3) 
AND j.date_debut BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-10-23 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY j.date_debut, j.date_fin, j.titre, so.id_identite, so.nom_societe,r.nom_responsable
```

Answer (score 0):

Join only the desired columns with a distinct statement for the table individus

```
 SELECT  j.date_debut, j.date_fin, j.titre, so.id_identite, so.nom_societe,
                SUM(CASE WHEN (i.statut_collaborateur = 'granted') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS interne, 
                SUM(CASE WHEN (i.statut_collaborateur = 'no') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS externe, 
                r.nom_responsable 
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT i.id_individu ,i.statut_collaborateur from individus )AS i 
            LEFT JOIN suivis AS s ON s.id_individu = i.id_individu 
            LEFT JOIN jurys AS j ON j.id_jury = s.id_jury 
            LEFT JOIN societes AS so ON so.id_societe = j.id_societe 
            LEFT JOIN responsables AS r ON r.id_responsable = j.id_responsable 
        WHERE s.id_action = 22 
        AND j.statut IN (1,3) 
        AND j.date_debut BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-10-23 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY j.date_debut, j.date_fin, j.titre, so.id_identite, so.nom_societe,r.nom_responsable
```

Comment: In your case does suivis table has duplicates for id_indvidu then you need to so the same by getting the distinct of needed columns.

Comment: The problem is your aggregation function is not aggregating according to your desire since some extra column is becoming more granular, to avoid that rewrite the query while joining the distinct of needed columns for each table